# How do I convert an excel file to a .db file

Tags: excel, database, file

I'm confused on how to do this. The excel plugin to make a database query doesn't work for me. And I don't want to make a query I just want to convert my excel file to a .db file

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

- Open Access.
- Ribbon > External Data > Excel

[image]

- Import the source data into a new table

[image]

- Save as `*.accdb`